# Selenium - Only able to select the first element in a list whereas able to print all elements

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to loop through a drop-down menu, I am able to get each and every listed element but when I use the `.click()` and `.submit()` commands, it selects the first one and does not continue any further. I am aware for it to continue any further, I need to reselect the drop-down arrow so the list becomes visible to selenium after every submit. I tried commenting to make it readable. ANY help is greatly appreciated.

I wrote down the following,

```
WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.id("search-form"));
WebElement arrowDownButton = search.findElement(By.className("dropdown-toggle"));
arrowDownButton.click();


WebElement menu = search.findElement(By.className("dropdown-menu"));



List <WebElement> listOptions = menu.findElements(By.tagName(LI)); //selecting the listed elements , LI is "li" (declared previously)


int numberOfCountries = listOptions.size();
log("We have " + numberOfCountries + " entires");
int i=0; //for looping 
//store into an array because web elements disappear
WebElement []listOfCountries = new WebElement[listOptions.size()]; //making an array of size listed elements
for (WebElement aOption : listOptions)
{
    listOfCountries[i] = aOption; //saving the value into an array
    String dataValue = aOption.getAttribute("data-value"); // what country am I wanting click
    i++;
}

for(WebElement country : listOfCountries)
{
    log(country.getText()); //log is a another function executing System.out.println
    country.click(); //clicking on the web element
    country.submit(); // submitting the element
    arrowDownButton.click(); //reselecting the drop-down menu -> Why isn't this working?
}

}
```

Here are some methods I have already tried:
Instead of creating, saving and iterating through an array, I just directly tried to click the element. However, it also just clicks the first element.

Here is the error I am receiving: 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with `arrowDownButton.click();` but I cannot figure out WHY it fails to RESELECT.

Comment: In the for loop(Don't use for-each loop), delete the element that is already selected.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! May I know why did you recommend me to not use a for-each loop? For learning purposes?

Comment: In general (Not respect to this problem), each time in the loop fetches all the webelements in the List & then considers the element on which current loop should run which results in performance issue. And some times if the form refreshed/ updated when the execution cursor is within the for loop, test will fail.

Comment: what error/exception you have?

Comment: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Comment: To make the element in view, I am using the arrowButtonDown.click() but it does not reselect the list

Comment: On selecting dropdown entry form (html) is refreshed or updated?

Comment: I found the error, it is you cannot use WebElement cause it is similar to a pointer and once I execute a function, it loses that point. I use string and made another function that searches that string in the combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(WebElement country : listOfCountries)
{
    log(country.getText()); //log is a another function executing System.out.println
    country.click(); //clicking on the web element

    Thread.Sleep(500);
    country.submit(); // submitting the element

  // You have to reselect this element. Because doesn't make sense anymore.
  // Try reselect next element
    arrowDownButton.click(); //reselecting the drop-down menu -> Why isn't this working?
```

}

Comment: I'm afraid adding a thread.sleep wasn't the problem . I had already tried it before. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

see if ur drop down menu is not in a select list, probably it is, in that case ur current code wont work. It will be helpful if you could post the Html code of the webelement ur trying to interact with.